# Psycopg2 cannot find temp table created within connection block

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I am having a strange issue with temp tables in psycopg2.

What I am trying to do is create a temp table, copy data into the table with the `copy_from` method on the psycopg2 cursor, and then upsert that data into the permenant target table (identical schema to the temp table).  I am trying to do this all within a single transaction.

I am testing with a alpine posgres docker image.

To repro, i am using the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: my-postgres-container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: test
      POSTGRES_USER: testuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpass
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

Then I have the python code:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(**pg_connection)
with conn.cursor() as curr:
    curr.execute("SET search_path TO test")
    temp_table_stmt = (
        "CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table ON COMMIT DROP AS\n"
        "SELECT *\n"
        "FROM table\n"
        "WHERE false;"
    )
    curr.execute(temp_table_stmt)
    fileobj : StringIO # buffer containing csv data to upload
    columns : ["column1", "column2"]
    curr.copy_from(fileobj, temp_table, columns)
```

The problem I have right now is the curr.copy_from throws an error saying that `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "temp_table" does not exist`.

I am baffled by this, as this is all happening on within the same session and cursor block.  From what I read, I have set up the temp table correctly and it is scoped within the transaction.

My db is just a single instance of postgres setup with the docker-compose above running locally. I am not using pgbouncer or any other external connection pooling.

I have also tried using `connect` as a context manager, but the same issue happens.  Setting `autocommit=False` on the connection does not help either, but I would like to do that so the whole thing happens within a single atomic commit.

Is what I am trying to do impossible? Is there an issue with my db configuration or anything wrong with my code?

Comment: 1) This `curr.execute("SET search_path TO test")` is probably not doing what you think it is. Temporary tables are created in temp schemas, you cannot assign them to an existing schema. 2) A quick test of similar code works for me. 3) Take a look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database. 4) In `curr.copy_from(fileobj, temp_table, columns)` where is `temp_table` defined? If that definition is something like `test.temp_table` then see 1).

Comment: Did some poking around: I got rid of search path, and added query immediately after create that lists all temp tables from the table catalogue. I DO see my table is created with the name, but trying copy immediately after that with that name still throws `relation does not exist`.  

I must be incorrectly addressing the table in the copy command.  Or it's not visible from the search path.  When you got it working, is there anything else you had to do to make sure the temp table was visible?

Comment: 1) As I added to my previous comment how and where is `temp_table` in `curr.copy_from(fileobj, temp_table, columns)` defined? 2) Again what does the Postgres log show?

Comment: You pointed me in the right path, it seems the issue was with the casing of the name, in my actual code, I had Temp_{table_name}, changing it to temp_{table_name} fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help!